# Problem with displaying pivot table in the Viewer pane using rpivotTable package

Tags: r, pivot-table, rpivottable

I am trying to use `rpivotTable` function to manage a dataset.

Unfortunately, I am new to R and I am unable to work out how to display the pivot table in the "Viewer" pane.

`rpivotTable package` is successfully installed, here is my code:

```
library(rpivotTable)
data("mtcars")
rpivotTable(mtcars)
```

No pivot table displayed in the "Viewer" pane (it should be displayed automatically). Does anybody have an idea of how to work around this?

[image]

Comment: do you have an active desktop firewall that is blocking some ports on localhost?

Comment: I don't think so :(

Answer (score 0):

You could try clicking "Show in New Window", the icon next to the clear icon in the viewer pane.